# Laravel Roles and authentication to routes

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-routing

I am looking to archive the the following

Userlogs in -> Assigned a privilege from the DB -> They can only see allowed routes only

So far i have been able to reach here:

```
$user = Usercredential::where('username','=',Auth::user()->username)->get();

foreach ($user as $u ) {

        $status = $u->userstatus;
        $userPriv = $u->userpriviledge;

        if ($status == 0){  
                           Session::put('user_priv',$userPriv);
            }
        else{
                    return Redirect::to_route('home')->with('message','Inactive users cannot login');
            }
```

Which checks the status of the user if active or inactive then stores the priviledge in my session. What next? How do i protect my routes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those in the future who are looking for this solution

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/build-web-apps-from-scratch-with-laravel-filters-validations-and-files/

Will be very helpful, thanks Rodri for your pointer. 
I appreciate.

Comment: Can you add relevant information from the link to your answer? Link only answers can become useless if the link breaks.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you the Laravel 4 Package called: [ENTRUST](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) who provide a way to add Role-based

Comment: Is there no way to do it using Laravel Auth?

Comment: Of Course you can, take a look at the documentation http://four.laravel.com/docs/security and read about filters. As a personal opinion, I don't give it a try reinventing the wheel in the problem of roles and auth, thats because someone solved that problem in Laravel 4.