# Get list of all controllers and action in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and would like to fetch list of all controllers and list of action in that controller.
Just want to know if there is a way to get a list of all Controllers as well as all their Methods by code?

Thanks,
DJ

Comment: What do you want to achieve, some web-service stuff?

Comment: Hi @KA_lin i am building a access related system in which i want to allow access to actions and controllers on role basis. i wiil be having a screen where super admin can select controller and respective action and the particular role will be given access to that route.

Comment: This might answer your question from a brief read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672064/laravel-roles-and-authentication-to-routes

Comment: Hi @KA_lin, i want list of all controllers in my controller. this won't work

Comment: Hey, I don`t know if there is a Laravel library for this but you can do this with http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php , check if the class is in the Controllers namespace and foreach class get methods

Comment: Hey, i tried it and was getting bunch of actions in under my controller, as it is also fetching middelware actions and all others action associated with a controller initialization. it is hard to find a simple method to fetch only declared methods in that controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79427/discussion-between-deejay-and-ka-lin).

Comment: Can this help? array_diff(get_class_methods('MyClass'), get_class_methods('BaseController'));

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By how you are explaining the need for you to know the controller actions, it seems that the actions are already mapped to routes, which means you can use the routes to get the list of mapped controllers and actions. The following code will generate an array of the registered route controller actions:

```
$controllers = [];

foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route)
{
    $action = $route->getAction();

    if (array_key_exists('controller', $action))
    {
        // You can also use explode('@', $action['controller']); here
        // to separate the class name from the method
        $controllers[] = $action['controller'];
    }
}
```

This will ignore routes that have Closures mapped, which you don't need. Mind you, you might need to filter out any matches from routes registered by third party packages.

Comment: Good stuff. Works pretty well. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Can also get this way. 

    $routes = Route::getRoutes();

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me.

Extracting all controllers (App\Http\Controllers)

```
$controllers = require_once base_path('vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php');
$controllers = array_keys($controllers);
$controllers = array_filter($controllers, function ($controller) {
    return strpos($controller, 'App\Http\Controllers') !== false;
});

$controllers = array_map(function ($controller) {

    return str_replace('App\Http\Controllers\\', '', $controller);
}, $controllers);

dd($controllers);
```

Extracting all methods in a specific controller using [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
$namespace = "App\Http\Controllers";
$controller = "TestController";
$controller_class = new ReflectionClass($namespace.'\\'.$controller);
$controller_methods = $controller_class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
dd($controller_methods);
```

One catch though. You may need to run composer dump-autoload after creating a controller.

Answer (score 1):

> Old code:

```
public static function Controllers()
{
    $controllers = require_once base_path('vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php');
    $controllers = array_keys($controllers);
    $controllers = array_filter($controllers, function ($controller) {
        return strpos($controller, 'App\Http\Controllers') !== false;
    });
    $controllers = array_map(function ($controller) {

        return str_replace('App\Http\Controllers\\', '', $controller);
    }, $controllers);

    return $controllers;
}
```

> Edited:

This Code is much better:

```
public static function Controllers()
{
    $classes = array_filter(get_declared_classes(), function ($class) {
        $isController = substr($class, -10) == 'Controller';
        $isNotPlainController = $isController && substr($class, -11) != '\Controller';
        return $isNotPlainController;
    });

    //Optional: to clear controller name from its namespace
    $controllers=array_map(function ($controller){
        return last(explode('\\',$controller));
    },$classes);

    //Optional: to reset keys of array to start from 0,1,2,...etc
    $controllers = array_values($controllers);

    return $controllers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Grep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) can be used to print a list of all actions per controller on unix systems.

Open a console in the laravel project root and execute the following command:

```bash
grep "public function" app/Http/Controllers/* -r
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();

foreach ($classes as $class) {
    if (is_subclass_of($class, 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller')) {
        echo $class . '<br />';
        $methods = get_class_methods($class);
        foreach ($methods as $method)
            echo '--- ' . $method . '<br />';
    }
}
```

It should output all your controllers (anything inherited from the Controller class) and their methods.

I'm not sure how to tell which ones of the methods are actual controller actions though. If you use controller routes that would be the ones starting with "get", "post" or "any", but if you're using direct links that's not the case.

Comment: Hi @MaGnetas this will return me the list of all methods binded with the controller, eg i have declared only 3 methods in my controller but it is returning me 28 actions.

Comment: If that's the only problem you might be able to extract only defined (not inherited) methods this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712671/get-only-declared-methods-of-a-class-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        $controllers = [];
        $i=0;
        foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route)
        {
            $action = $route->getAction();

            if (array_key_exists('controller', $action))
            {

                $_action = explode('@',$action['controller']);
                $_namespaces_chunks = explode('\\',$_action[0]);

                $controllers[$i]['controller'] = end($_namespaces_chunks);
                $controllers[$i]['action'] = end($_action);
                $controllers[$i]['namespace'] = $action['controller'];
                $controllers[$i]['route'] = $route;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        dump($controllers);
```